# Base page wpf. The name X does not exists in the namespace Y

Tags: wpf, namespaces

I decided to create a Base page for my WPF project. 
When I create the base page and an inherited page inside the project's namespace it works OK, but when I create a folder named Pages in the project and the base page and an inherited page inside the folder and it's namespace it says that the BasePage does not exists in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.Pages".

This is the base page. It is just a plain class with no XAML.

```
namespace WpfApplication2.Pages
{
    public class BasePage : Page
    {
    }
}
```

The inherited page's .cs file

```
namespace WpfApplication2.Pages
{

   public partial class Page1 : BasePage
   {
      public Page1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
}
```

The first row of the inherited page. The part I change from Page to local:BasePage. It causes the error.

```
<local:BasePage x:Class="WpfApplication2.Pages.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.Pages"
```

Screenshot requested by Ed Plunkett:

[image: Screenshot of the project explorer using Page as a rootElement in Page1.xaml]

Comment: I was able to get this exact code to work. My suspicion is that there is something else going on. Did you *create* `Page1` in the `Pages` folder, or move it there? Moving it there might create havoc.

Comment: I created it inside it. This is BasePage `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication4.Pages
{
    public class BasePage : Page
    {
    }
}`

Comment: Page1.xaml.cs  `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication4.Pages
{
  
    public partial class Page1 : BasePage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: Are you able to read that? I can't. Please put code in the question where it belongs.

Comment: It's just the same as in the question.

Comment: OK. No need to paste it in then.

Comment: I already found this error days ago and people always solved it using using something like <local:BasePage. They just didn't try to create the classes in a folder.

Comment: The folder makes no difference for me.

Comment: Can you post the project somewhere?

Comment: I've recreated it twice, no problems either time, exactly as you have it, creating BasePage and Page1 in a Pages folder. You were right about `<local:BasePage ...` being necessary.

Comment: Wait, here's an idea: Can you show me the XAML where you USE the page? How is `local` defined in that file? I bet that's it. In MainWindow, for example, you'll see `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"` -- a different namespace.

Comment: Wait, I just don't understand. I changed the root element back to local:BasePage and it works. I didn't change anything else. Ok, I think that's it, although I don't get it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to suspect the problem is that you're trying to create `Page1` like so:

```
<local:Page1 />
```

...but in a XAML file where `local` is `WpfApplication1` rather than `WpfApplication1.Pages`. MainWindow, for example. When I do that, I see the "name ... does not exist" error:

> The name "Page1" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication1". WpfApplication1 C:\Users\edplunkett\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test2\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml 14

In that case, just define another xmlns for `WpfApplication1.Pages`:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Pages"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="350" 
    Width="525"
    >
    <pages:Page1 
        />
</Window>
```

Sorry I wasted your time on blind alleys here.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is the root element and using Page as root element? What do your mean by that?

Comment: I get The namespace 'WpfApplication2.Pages' already contains a definition for 'BasePage' and a Type 'Page1' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types errors using Page as the root element. The problem is that it works OK when I create the BasePage and Page1 inside the project's namespace and it doesn't work inside a folder.

Comment: I created a new project and now I am not getting any errors, but the app won't start saying the were build errors... This happens when I have issues generated by build+IntelliSense, when i change it to build only I am getting a Partial declaration of 'Page1' must not specify different base classes when the root element in Page1.xaml is Page and when I use localhost:BasePage as the root element I get BasePage does not exists in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.Pages" on build+IntelliSense

Comment: @Myoxidae Try restarting VS and doing a clean build.

Comment: I restarted the VS, but the build fails becasue of the "Partial declaration of 'Page1' must not specify different base classes when the root element in Page1.xaml' error in build only mode. Pages look just like those in the question

Comment: Are you saying that you're still trying to make `<local:BasePage` work?

Comment: That actually works for me, anyhow. I can't reproduce the error you're getting.

Comment: I am not trying to make <local:BasePage work anymore. Althoughit it works when the classes are directly in the project's namespace. Not in a folder. So using a folder and Page as the root element I am still getting the error when issues generated are on build only and I can't build the program because it says there are errors.

Comment: You didn't waste my time and I still don't quite understand this because it just started working without me doing anything else than changing Page back to local:BasePage, I opened previous projects and i do not get the error anymore.

Comment: @Myoxidae Bizarre. Maybe it finally cleaned the build properly. Well, I'm glad to hear it's working.